# Prolonged jumping sprite in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, physics, game-physics

Im building a 2d platformer, and right now am trying to have my player jump longer when you hold down the space bar. Right now the player can jump up and down, but id like that effect that robot unicorn has when you hold down the key. How would I go about doing this? Im not using phaser or anything, and most tutorials ive seen uses that. Heres what I have in my update method:

```
     var gameEngine = this.game;

if (gameEngine.keyMap["Space"] && !this.jumping) { //only jump if not already in mid jump

    this.jumping = true;
    this.animationCurrent.elapsedTime = 0;
    this.game.space = false;
}

if (this.jumping) {

    if (this.animationCurrent.isDone()) {
        this.animationCurrent.elapsedTime = 0;
        this.jumping = false;
    }

    var jumpDistance = this.animationCurrent.elapsedTime /
        this.animationCurrent.totalTime;

    var totalHeight = 150;

    if (jumpDistance > 0.5)
        jumpDistance = 1 - jumpDistance;
    var height = totalHeight * (-4 * (jumpDistance * jumpDistance - jumpDistance));
    this.y = this.ground - height;
    console.log(this.y);
}
```

Comment: Are you using onkeypressed? If so, this is probably not possible by design. Are you using onkeydown? If so, this will allow you to throttle the jump height over time as a bonus. +150, +15, +5, +1, for example.

Comment: @TravisJ I am using onkeydown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to implement a system by which holding down the jump key continues to apply a gradually decreasing force to the character.

It looks like you're tying jump height into an animation at the moment? Not ideal for exactly this reason; tweaking stuff becomes a ball ache. You need more of a physics based approach.

basic back of the envelope pseudo code:

Old style constant jump motion:

```
const JUMP_STRENGTH = 100;
const GRAVITY = 10;

onJumpKeyupPress(){
    if(play.canJump)
    player.transform.up.velocity = JUMP_STRENGTH;

}

gameTick(){
    if(!player.onGround)
    {
        player.up.velocity -= GRAVITY
        player.y += player.up.velocity;
    }
    else{
        player.up.velocity = 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this uses gravity to pull down on the player character overtime. But all the force is applied at once when the user pushed jump

Bigger Jump Whilst Holding jump key:

```
const JUMP_STRENGTH = 100;
const GRAVITY = 10;

var jumpStrength = 0;

onJumpKeyupPress(){
    if(play.canJump)
    jumpStrength = JUMP_STRENGTH;
}

gameTick(){
    if(!player.onGround)
    {
        if(jumpKeyIsStillPressed){
            player.up.velocity += jumpStrength;
            jumpStrength /= 2;
        }
        player.up.velocity -= GRAVITY;
        player.y += player.up.velocity;
    }
    else{
        player.up.velocity = 0;
        jumpStrength = 0;
    }
}
```

With this example, the user gets an initial jump strength of 100, which is halved with each tick until gravity is stronger.

Hopefully I've been clear enough!

Comment: this works pretty well! my only problem is that it jumps down instead of going up, how would i fix this?

Comment: I think i figured it out, I changed player.y += player.up.velocity to player.y -= player.up.velocity

Comment: is there a way to make the jump go faster? it goes up and down super slow, even when i change the gravity

Comment: You'd need to increase the forces involved. Probably by an order of magnitude. Increase jump strength and gravity by a large amount and see what difference it makes.